Android FlatList dynamically adds and deletes lists, the list shakes
I am using flatlist to simulate a message comment area. A message is added every 500ms and scrolls to the bottom. When the list exceeds the length, the header data needs to be deleted after the scrolling is completed. At this time, the list jitters.
It only appears on Android devices，that detail code :
import React, { type VFC, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import {
    FlatList,
    type NativeScrollEvent,
    type NativeSyntheticEvent,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: '#ccc',
        height: 78,
        marginTop: 100,
        position: 'relative',
    },
});

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 26;

const getItemLayout = (_: any, index: number) => ({
    length: ITEM_HEIGHT,
    offset: ITEM_HEIGHT * index,
    index,
});
// render item
const renderItem = ({ item }: { item: any }) => (
    <View
        style={{
            alignItems: 'center',
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            height: 20,
            marginBottom: 6,
        }}
    >
        <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>{item?.text}</Text>
    </View>
);

let time = 0;
const log = (...args: any) => {
    let d = Date.now();
    [time, d] = [d, d - time];
    console.log(d.toString().padStart(5), ...args);
};

let contentH = 0;

const App: VFC = () => {
    const MAX = 10; // renderList max length
    const emptyLen = 3; // mock empty view
    const [renderList, setRenderList] = useState(() => new Array(emptyLen).fill({
            id: Math.random().toString(),
            text: Math.random().toString() + '-name',
        }));
    const bufferList = useRef(
        new Array(100).fill(0).map(() => ({
            id: Math.random().toString(),
            text: Math.random().toString() + '-name',
        })),
    );
    const listRef = useRef<FlatList<any>>(null);
    const [updateEnabled, setUpdateEnabled] = useState(true);
    const scrollTimer = useRef(0);

    // forbid scroll when person slide
    const onScrollBeginDrag = () => {
        if (scrollTimer.current) clearTimeout(scrollTimer.current);
        setUpdateEnabled(false);
        scrollTimer.current = setTimeout(() => {
            setUpdateEnabled(true);
        }, 1000);
    };

    const handleScroll = (event: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeScrollEvent>) => {
        const offsetY = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
        const contentHeight = event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height;
        const screenHeight = event.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.height;

        if (offsetY + screenHeight >= contentHeight) {
            const LEN = renderList.length;
            log('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', offsetY, screenHeight, contentHeight, LEN > MAX);
             if (LEN > MAX) {
                console.log('@slice----------------');
                // setRenderList(list => list.slice(-MAX));
            }
        }
    };

    const onContentSizeChange = (_, h) => {
        if (h > contentH) {
            console.log('@scroll-----------------');
            listRef.current?.scrollToEnd();
        }
        contentH = h;
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (updateEnabled && bufferList.current.length) {
                const newItem = bufferList.current.pop();
                log('@add');
                setRenderList(list => [...list, newItem]);
            }
        }, 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [updateEnabled, bufferList]);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={renderList}
                ref={listRef}
                onScroll={handleScroll}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                keyExtractor={item => item?.id || Math.random().toString()}
                removeClippedSubviews={true}
                getItemLayout={getItemLayout}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                scrollEventThrottle={16}
                onContentSizeChange={onContentSizeChange}
                onScrollBeginDrag={onScrollBeginDrag}
            />
        </View>
    );
};

export default App;

try different props in Flatlist
it's more appear on Android
the detail video:
https://github-production-user-asset-6210df.s3.amazonaws.com/78007999/345759366-21fc24c9-4faa-4209-83e9-984285e3b5ce.mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAVCODYLSA53PQK4ZA%2F20240704%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20240704T084900Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=1332371438bb72e3bfe3570493a588b16e0fd6363fc422fc9a24dc391c542d5e&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=78007999&key_id=0&repo_id=29028775
